# Can I use NULL as part of a MySQL select statement where results are `IN (1,2,NULL)`?

Tags: mysql, arrays, select, null

Is it possible to include a `NULL` inside of a statement like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_field IN (1,2,NULL);`?

If not, how do you recommend allowing for only a few integers or NULL?

Is it best to use an `OR` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE
   my_field IN (1,2)
OR my_field IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `OR`, it's the clearest expression of what you want.

You can also provide a default value to use when `my_field` is `NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE COALESCE(my_field, 1) IN (1,2);
```

But using a `NULL` in an `IN`-list will not work, since `NULL` is *usually* not equal to `NULL`. (It's not un-equal either — it's undefined).

Comment: Hello @Ryan, is this an _acceptable_ answer?